# "import cycle not allowed" with go install

Tags: go, package, cycle

Folks- I'm not able to understand this:

My code layout:

src/rtagent/rtagent.go (has package main)

src/simplerouter/simplerouter.go (has package simplerouter)

src/p4/p4runtime.pb.go (has package p4)

### rtagent.go:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/reflection"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "p4"
    "simplerouter"
    p4_config "p4/config"
)
```

### simplerouter.go

```
package simplerouter
import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "p4"
    "p4InfoUtils"
    "strings"
    "unsafe"
)
```

### p4runtime.pb.go

```
package p4
import proto "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
import fmt "fmt"
import math "math"
import google_protobuf "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/any"
import google_rpc "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status"
import p4_config "p4/config"
import p41 "p4"
import (
    context "golang.org/x/net/context"
    grpc "google.golang.org/grpc"
)
```

I get this error:

```
go install rtagent
import cycle not allowed
package rtagent
        imports p4
        imports p4
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: @aristofanio-garcia, added the info

Comment: Do not use local import. Dead simple. Read How to Write Go Code and _stick_ _to_ _it_ _word_ _for_ _word. And stop renaming your import.

Comment: Please use `gofmt`. Your code is very hard to read--especially due to mixing import styles.

Comment: I should have mentioned, p4runtime.pb.go is the code generated by the google protobuf compiler. This was generated for a .proto file I picked up from an opensourced project. I also found the issue in the .proto file.
Basically, there are 3 .proto files. 
1.proto -> package a
2.proto, 3.proto -> package b

1.proto imports 2.proto, and 3.proto imports 1.proto. This causes the loop. I've filed a bug against that project to fix this loop.

Thanks folks.

Answer (score 1):

The error message pretty much says it all:

`rtagent` imports `p4` which in turn imports `p4` (itself).  This is not allowed.

Your code makes this obvious, too:

```
package p4
// <snip>
import p41 "p4"  // <-- importing itself
```